# integer solution of $(x-y)(x+y)xy=z^2$

Tags: number-theory

By wolfram alpha, integer solution of  $(x-y)(x+y)xy=z^2$ is $x=y=z=0$.
How to show that there are not another solutions with $z \neq 0$.
Thanks.

Comment: Certainly each of $x = \pm y, z = 0$, $x = z = 0$, and $y = z = 0$ are solutions too.

Comment: @Clayton Oops, you're right, of course, I've fixed it.

Comment: What about $x=y \neq 0$, $z=0$?

Comment: Thanks. Are there another solutions with $z\neq 0$.

Comment: There is infinitely many solutions !!

Comment: No solution unless $z=0$.

Comment: Certainly, no solution exists for odd $z$, as the R.H.S. is odd.  The lefthand side will be even if either $x$ or $y$ is even, and will also be even if both $x$ and $y$ are odd (since $x^2-y^2$ would be odd-odd=even), and even$\neq$odd.  The case where $z$ is even doesn't come quite so quickly...

Comment: Also, $z\equiv 0\mod 3$ so the whole expression is divisible by $36$ (if a solution exists, though I don't believe it does). Not sure where to go from here, though.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b) = d$, and $(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$ is a nontrivial solution, then $(\frac{a}{d},  \frac{b}{d},\frac{c}{d^2})$ is also a solution, where $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}) = 1$.  So if there is no solution $(a,b,c)$ having $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then there are no nontrivial solutions.

Assume $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.  We want to find $a$ and $b$ where the expression $(a+b)(a-b)ab$ would be a perfect square.  But $(a+b)$, $(a-b)$, and their product $(a^2-b^2)$ are all coprime to both $a$ and $b$.  So it is necessary that $a$ and $b$ are both squares, because any unsquared factors they may have will not be able to have their squares completed by the other terms.

$a = a'^2$ and $b = b'^2$.  $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2 = a'^4 - b'^4$.  If there is a solution, then there must be some $c$ where $c^2 = a'^4 - b'^4$, or $c^2 + b'^4 = a'^4$.  Fermat [proved this was impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Non-solvability_of_r2_.2B_s4_.3D_t4), so there cannot be any nontrivial solutions.

Comment: I fear (am I wrong?) what Fermat proved was the impossibility of the sum $x^4+y^4 = z^2$ (not the difference!) then $x^4+y^4 = z^4$ as historical sources told. I realized now that this last (not the first) implies $x^4-y^4 = z^2$ impossible too. What I want here is just to EMPHASIZE that I am not such a brute to have wished to cheat people of StackSchange with a proof well known to all. I spent a whole day trying to prove $X^4 – y^4 = z^2$ and I have posted it around midnight (I confess that I thought to myself why no one put a comment about the proof)

Comment: No one is persecuting you.  There may be a good proof hiding behind what you've written, but what you've written lacks clarity.

Comment: "No one is persecuting you" (?) I don't feel it at all. Write $(x,y) = k$ (french notation) instead of $gcd(x,y) = k$ is darkness?. You have write with other words exactly what I did, excepting the proof of $x^4-y^4 = z^2$. I stop here, no more comments. Believe me please, I have nothing against you and my comment was just for the EMPHASIS above. Best regards.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood.  Again, your math may be good but your English is unclear.

Comment: without quite imperfect translation of Google (which I correct a lot because I know something of English and I read a lot), it would be impossible for me to write to StackSchange. My respects, dear friend. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If $(x,y)=k$ then $k^4(x_1-y_1)(x_1+y_1)x_1y_1= z^2$ which implies an equation (we use the same notation) $(x-y)(x+y)xy=z^2$ with $(x,y)=1$; it follows that $(x+y,x-y)=1$  ($x+y=mX$ and $x-y=mY$ give clearly a contradiction). Hence $x-y,  x+y, x, y$ are four coprime integers and each of them must be a square, $x, y$ being of different parity (if not then $2|(x-y,x+y)=1$).

We have three pythagorean triples to which we apply the well known parametrization
$(a,b,c) =(p^2-q^2, 2pq, p^2+q^2)$:

(1)………………$x^2=y^2+u^2$

(2)……………..$x^2+y^2=v^2$

(3)…………….$x^4+y^4=(uv)^2$

If $y$ were odd then $x$ would be odd in (1) and even in (2), absurde, so $y$ must be even.

Now from (3)
$x^2=t^2+s^2, y^2=2ts$ implies $ {x^4-y^4=(t^2-s^2)^2}$ , $t$ and $s$ of distinct parity.
Since $t^2+s^2=x^2$, we write $t=m^2-n^2, s=2mn$ and $x=m^2+n^2$  with $(m,n)=1$.

It follows $y^2=2(m^2-n^2)(2mn)=4(m^2-n^2)mn$
Hence $m=p^2, n=q^2$ and $y^2=4(p^2-q^2)p^2q^2$ and since y is even,$(p^2-q^2)(p^2+q^2)p^2q^2= w^2$.

Thus, from $(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2=z^2$ we have got another equation
$(p^2-q^2)(p^2+q^2)p^2q^2= w^2$ similar to the first one with the values of $p,q$ less than the values of $x, y$. This process can be iterated indefinitely therefore, by infinite descent,  we finish the proof.

Comment: What about solutions of the form (t,-t,0)?

Comment: THE TRUE QUESTION IS EXPLICITLY ABOUT THE EXISTENCE OF SOLUTIONS WITH  $z\neq0$

Comment: $(x,y) = 1$ does not imply that $(x+y,x-y) = 1$.  Counterexample is $x=3$, $y=1$.

Comment: @Théophile: go to the beach and swimming slowly.

Comment: @NovaDenizen And in fact, any odd $x$ and $y$ will ensure that $(x+y,x-y) \geq 2$.